# How to make some Cotton Candy?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, particles, sculpting

I want to make cotton candies like the reference image attached below. Since I need multiple cotton candies I also want the colour to vary as I duplicate them (just like the reference image, sometimes more green sometimes pinker) I want to achieve the same shape as the candies in the image, the same texture, and the same level of detail. Is this possible in Blender?

I've been searching tutorials and websites, but no luck. It's always either cotton or clouds. No realistic-looking cotton candy tutorials. The shape, the materials, and the textures are a little complex, so I don't understand them.

Also, I want the colour gradient to vary as I duplicate the object as shown in the multiple cotton candies in the image.

[image]

Comment: Hello, do you have a bigger picture of the same material?

Comment: I thinks yes let me post it

Comment: @moonboots I edited it to be bigger

Comment: The prior closed question is at https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/263728/15795

Comment: @ChaudhryYousuf Check out https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions in case you have another closed question down the road.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe put the *Specular* at 0, give a grainy color with a *Noise Texture*, mix a pink area with a blue area, also a bit of *Subsurface Scattering*, and some bumps:

[image]

And also use a *Displace* modifier in order to give real bumps to your cotton:

[image]

If you use a particle system to make hair, you need to remove the *Subsurface Scattering* from the material or choose another material for the hair.

If you want to duplicate your object but want to make sure that the material will appear slightly different on each instance, create an empty and select it at the bottom of the *Texture Coordinate* node, now it's the empty that will determine the location, rotation and scale of the material:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it have some strands like in the image?

Comment: Should the strands be added using particles?

Comment: And also, using this material node setup, the size/location of the gradient doesn't vary when I duplicate it, how should I do that (like in the image)

Comment: it was not clear if there was hair but yes you can create a particle system

Comment: And how should I randomize the gradient as the object duplicates?

Comment: At the bottom of the Texture Coordinate, you can choose an empty that will determine the location of the textures you'll use, so that each object will have a different texture

Comment: @moonboots Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Chris I actually just wanted to know how to duplicate the candy in the image and how to make the gradient vary as stated in the question... I got an answer so I guess that's it...:) And the problem making it was that I don't know how to make it ;)

Comment: @Chris the comment section is for clarification of a given answer, to express problems with a given answer or discuss techniques used in that answer. From the docs: 'Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer.' Its explicitly stated not to use the comment section just to thank for an answer.

Comment: i know the comments are not for politeness and most of the people here aren't polite. But i don't care about some rules because - this is just my opinion - this is why a lot of people are struggling with this kind of forum here. Just my opinion. But i am for sure not the only one who is not fan of the rules here....but thank you very much for repeating the rules here! I am so happy you know the rules!

Comment: Hopefully you're not looking to simulate the process of actually making cotton candy from scratch in the spinning machine - that would be some advanced stuff.  I have some ideas floating around for how you'd pull it off (some kind of cloth simulation maybe?), but it would be a lot more work...

Comment: @Chris as time goes on, your politeness is getting more and more aggressive 

Comment: I know - that’s why i am not so active here anymore and I think this forum will die anyway - because of the annoying people here and the unfair moderators. But then it‘s not my problem anymore…‍♂️there are a few nice one here -but unfortunately the annoying people will be saved by moderators. They can write wrong things, comment everything and annoy everyone. Nothing happens. But yeah…that’s life. There are much better forums than this is…fortunately.

Comment: And thankfulness isn’t wanted here…I know. But know-it-Alls are loved here.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all every third isn't active anymore....and this has reasons, i am sure!

Comment: i am just waiting now for my next punishment by the "great" moderators....now they can lock me for 3 month for saying the truth! :D and i don't even care....