# How can I make cotton batting or a material similar to it

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh, texturing, materials

[image]

[image]

I want to make this cotton batting in blender but having a hard time figuring out how to get this result. Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/263758/35559 ?

Comment: While this is a good base. It isn't giving that fluffy and slight see through texture I am looking for. I am wanting it to be as close to real as possible because it'll be used in close up